# Mobile(iphone) view issue

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

I am getting Mobile view issue, whenever I am loading the website it is going in the right direction. Every section is equal sized but dont know why this is happening. This problem is only with iphones..

I tried adding this code:

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

but it is also not working. Please help me solving this issue.

website link:
http://demo.lamppostmedia.in/arklan1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inspected it on iPhoneX which device width is `375px`.

and you are giving `width: 400px;` to wrapper, which is creating horizontal scroll bar.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.wrapper {
    margin-left: -15px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

you can use it like below.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.wrapper {
    margin-left: -15px;
    max-width: 400px; // modified
    width:100%;       // added
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```